# jq: delete element from array

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have this JSON file and want to delete an element from an array:

```json
{
"address": "localhost",
"name": "local",
"vars": {
    "instances": [
        "one",
        "two"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using this command:

```bash
jq 'del(.vars.instances[] | select(index("one")))' data.json
```

The output is:

```json
{
"address": "localhost",
"name": "local",
"vars": {
    "instances": [
        "two"
    ]
  }
}
```

So it works as expected, but only with jq v1.6. With jq v1.5 I get this error:

```
jq: error (at data.json:20): Invalid path expression near attempt to access element 0 of [0]
```

So what am I doing wrong? Is this a bug or a feature of v1.5? Is there any workaround to get the same result in v1.5?

Thanks in advance

Vince

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One portable to work with on both versions would be,

```
.vars.instances |= map(select(index("one")|not))
```

or if you want to still use `del()`, feed the index of the string `"one"` to the function as below, where `index("one")` gets the index `0` which then gets passed to delete as `del(.[0])` meaning to delete the element at zeroth index.

```
.vars.instances |= del(.[index("one")])
```

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of `del/1` has proven to be quite difficult and indeed it changed between jq 1.5 and jq 1.6, so if portability across different versions of jq is important, then usage of `del/1` should either be restricted to the least complicated cases (e.g., no pipelines) or undertaken with great care.